Snowflake JDBC FIPS driver in non fips mode
We have a requirement to use the JDBC FIPS driver in both FIPS and non-FIPS modes. When using the JDBC FIPS driver, it mandates that the BouncyCastleFipsProvider must always be at the top of Java's security providers list during connection establishment.
However, in non-FIPS mode, we do not want to keep BouncyCastleFipsProvider as the top provider because it causes issues when establishing connections with other databases, such as Oracle.
Our question is:
Is it acceptable to remove the BouncyCastleFipsProvider from the security providers list after the connection has been successfully established and the connection handle is obtained?
What is the significance of having BouncyCastleFipsProvider in the providers list when operating in non-FIPS mode?
Any insights or best practices on managing this scenario would be greatly appreciated.
